# Interactive Plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

i am trying to builkd a shiny app for rerolling a 6 sided dice.
a have 2 actionbuttons. and i want to implement, that each click on the reroll button will add another probabilityline on the SAME (!!) plot.

each probabilityline should be in another colour (so if you click 30 times on it, you will see 30 different coloured problines of the 6 as the result)

with the Restart button can you erase all printed graphs in the plot an can try from beginning (so if one line is altime printed could be also ok).

Here is waht i have created until now:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(extrafont)

ui <- fluidPage(

# Application title
titlePanel("Roll the dice"),

# Sidebar with a go_button and a restart_button
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  actionButton("reroll", 
               "ReRoll the dice", 
               width = "100%"),
  br(),
  br(),

  actionButton("restart", 
               "Restart", 
               width = "100%")
),

# Show a plot 
mainPanel(
  plotOutput("plot")
  )
 )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

output$plot <- renderPlot({

input$reroll

a <- 1:6
b <- 1:1000
eyes <- sample(a,1000,replace=T)
six <- eyes == 6
c <- cumsum(six) / 1:1000
df <- data.frame(b , c)


gl <- geom_line(aes(x = b , y = c), size = 0.9, linetype="dashed", colour = "red", alpha = 0.5)

p <-  ggplot(data = df) +
      xlim(0, 1000) +
      ylim(0, 1) +
      labs(x="Number of Throws", y="Probability of 6") +
      ggtitle("Approximation of Diceprobability") +

      theme_fivethirtyeight() + scale_colour_fivethirtyeight() +
      theme(axis.title = element_text(family="Atlas Grotesk Regular"),
              legend.position="bottom", legend.direction="horizontal",
              legend.title=element_blank(),
              plot.title=element_text(family="Atlas Grotesk Medium"),
              legend.text=element_text(family="Atlas Grotesk Regular"),
              text=element_text(family="DecimaMonoPro"))

p + gl

 })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server = server)
```

Questions:

1. How can i plot different lines in the same Plot (you know...i click 30 times an it builds 30 lines in the same plot)
2. How can i programm it, that each line has another colour?
3. how can i "erase" it with my restart button an can have another try?

I would be glad for each help in there :-)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

- Use `observeEvent` to trigger the buttons.
- Use `reactiveValues` to store the plot and a counter for the colors.
- Don't use that color scale, since it only has three colors.

Keep `ui` as it is, then make `server`:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  # start plot
  p_blank <- ggplot() +
    xlim(0, 1000) +
    ylim(0, 1) +
    labs(x="Number of Throws", y="Probability of 6") +
    ggtitle("Approximation of Diceprobability") +
    theme_fivethirtyeight() + 
    theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.direction="horizontal",
          legend.title=element_blank())

  #reactive values
  reac <- reactiveValues()
  reac$p_lines <- p_blank
  reac$counter <- 0

  # button functionality
  observeEvent(input$reroll,
               {
                 input$reroll
                 a <- 1:6
                 b <- 1:1000
                 eyes <- sample(a,1000,replace=T)
                 six <- eyes == 6
                 c <- cumsum(six) / 1:1000
                 df <- data.frame(b, c, counter = reac$counter)
                 gl <- geom_line(aes(x = b , y = c, col = factor(counter)), df, 
                                 size = 0.9,  linetype="dashed", alpha = 0.5)
                 reac$p_lines <- reac$p_lines + gl
                 reac$counter <- reac$counter + 1
               })

  observeEvent(input$restart,
               {
                 reac$p_lines <- p_blank
                 reac$counter <- 0
               } )

  # draw the plot
  output$plot <- renderPlot(reac$p_lines)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to acheive, over all but:

1. To update a plot I would set up a reactive value which holds your plot object. I would then use and observeEventto watch for a button press. Inside this event add on your new line.
2. You could then create an observeEvent for your other button to replace your plot object with an empty plot.